# SQL insert Invalid Month

Tags: mysql, date, insert

I am trying to do a simple insert on the table below. When ever I try run the insert I get an error saying `invalid month. I have tried changing the date format in SQL developer using tools>preferences>database>NLS>dateFormat. I have changed it to all the different variations and I still get`invalid month`. The current format is`mm/dd/yyyy`

**The Table**

```
  create table SALES_TABLE
  (
    outlet_number number(3),
    emp_number number(4),
    customer_ID number(4),
    product_code number(4),
    sale_date date not null,
    sale_time timestamp not null,
    quantity number(5) not null,
    foreign key (outlet_number) references OUTLET_TABLE(outlet_number),
    foreign key (emp_number) references EMPLOYEE_TABLE(emp_number),
    foreign key (customer_ID) references CUSTOMER_TABLE(customer_ID),
    foreign key (product_code) references PRODUCT_TABLE(product_code)
  );
```

**The Insert**

```
insert into SALES_TABLE (outlet_number, emp_number, customer_ID, product_code, sale_date, sale_time, quantity) values (10, 41, 7, 2, '01/20/2015', '4:20:00', 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is the value for the timestamp, and not the date, that's causing the error. The format that can be used as a valid timestamp is `1970-01-01 00:00:01`, for example.

You can find more details about MySql date and timestamp types [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)

Comment: I have changed the table to use TIME instead of TIMESTAMP but now it is sayingthat is is an invalid identifier?

Comment: why don't you combine both the date and time fields into a single one and use  `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` as the type for it? It will also save an extra column in your dbatabase.

Comment: Something like this...

`create table SALES_TABLE
  (
    outlet_number number(3),
    emp_number number(4),
    customer_ID number(4),
    product_code number(4),
    sale_date_time datetime not null,
    quantity number(5) not null,
    foreign key (outlet_number) references OUTLET_TABLE(outlet_number),
    foreign key (emp_number) references EMPLOYEE_TABLE(emp_number),
    foreign key (customer_ID) references CUSTOMER_TABLE(customer_ID),
    foreign key (product_code) references PRODUCT_TABLE(product_code)
  );`

Comment: and then to insert:

`insert into SALES_TABLE (outlet_number, emp_number, customer_ID, product_code, sale_date_time, quantity) values (10, 41, 7, 2, '2015-12-18 04:20:00', 3);`

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_to_date`

```
insert into SALES_TABLE 
(outlet_number, emp_number, customer_ID, product_code, 
sale_date, sale_time, quantity) 
values (10, 41, 7, 2, str_to_date('01/20/2015','%m/%d/%Y'), '4:20:00', 3);
```

Comment: Tried that and it gave me this `SQL Error: ORA-00904: "STR_TO_DATE": invalid identifier`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default SQL date format for the insert, *i.e*., '2015-01-20' (or '20150120') instead of '01/20/2015'?

Comment: ..and yes, I was thinking that the timestamp might also give you some trouble - better to declare it as a time variable...